# Define minimum length for PostgreSQL string column with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm defining an PostgreSQL table using an SQLAlchemy declarative base, like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, BigInteger
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    id = Column('id', BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    some_string = Column('some_string', String(256), nullable=False)
```

The `nullable` constraint guarantees that `some_string` cannot be `null`. However, I'd additionally like to give `some_string` a minimum length, or just forbid it from being the empty string. How can I do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ideally we want the validation to be applied both at the database layer via a constraint and *also* in our model by rejecting attempts to set the property to a string that's too short even before trying to save it to the database. We can do the former with a [`CheckConstraint`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.CheckConstraint) using the [`char_length`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) function, and the latter by adding a [validator](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_attributes.html#sqlalchemy.orm.validates). Below is an example that enforces a minimum length of 3 characters on `some_string`:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, BigInteger
from sqlalchemy.schema import CheckConstraint
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import validates
Base = declarative_base()

class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    id = Column('id', BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    some_string = Column('some_string', String(256), nullable=False)

    __table_args__ = (
        CheckConstraint('char_length(some_string) > 2',
                        name='some_string_min_length'),
    )

    @validates('some_string')
    def validate_some_string(self, key, some_string) -> str:
        if len(some_string) <= 2:
            raise ValueError('some_string too short')
        return some_string
```